# compare 2 column values in hive

Tags: hive

I am trying to compare 2 column values in hive using the below sample data

```
m_bldg_id       bldg_id                                 Indicator

1911            1968 19657 19658                            Not resident
19657           1968 19657 19658                            resident     
19658           1968 19657 19658                            resident
1968            1968 19657 19658                            resident   
19887           1968 19887 19658 16755 17543 34213          resident
11132           1968 19887 19658 16755 17543 34213          Not resident
```

I need to write a case statement to identify the indicator where if m_bldg_id like bldg_id then indicator is resident.So for the first row in the above data, m_bldg_id of 1911 is not in 1968 19657 19658 so the indicator value is not resident.In the second row m_bldg_id has a value of 19657 which is present in 
bldg_id value of '1968 19657 19658' so it should be resident.

I tried
 `CASE WHEN  m_bldg_id like %bldg_id% then 'resident' else 'not resident'` which did not work, please help

Answer (score 0):

Concat the `'%'` with field you are comparing

```
select 
     m_bldg_id,
     bldg_id,
     case 
        when m_bldg_id like '%' + bldg_id + '%' then 'resident' 
        else 'Non resident' 
     end as Indicator
from
tablename
```

Comment: i tried using your query but  the indicator is showing as  'not resident'  even when there is a match, any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Use `split()` + `array_contains()`:

```
select 
     m_bldg_id,
     bldg_id,
     case 
        when array_contains(split(bldg_id,' '),m_bldg_id ) then 'resident' 
        else 'Non resident' 
     end as Indicator
from tablename;
```

Or use `instr()` function:

```
case when instr(bldg_id, m_bldg_id) > 0 then 'resident' else 'Non resident' end as Indicator
```